# Can't change ADCs common mode voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to use below schematic to convert a single ended signal to a differential one. If I tie -Vs to GND the common mode voltage is +Vs. I used different +Vs values but the ADCs Vcm stays the same, why?

[image]

Comment: `I used different +Vs values but the ADCs Vcm stays the same` stays at what voltage? At 0V? At +Vs / 2? Normally, even if you left the CM pin floating then the output common-mode voltage will be the midpoint of supply rails (i.e. (+Vs + –Vs) / 2) because there is an on-chip 50k-50k divider. So, `If I tie -Vs to GND the common-mode voltage is +Vs.` no, it isn't. Even if you don't place 500R-500R dividers the CM pin voltage will be set to +Vs / 2. So, for –Vs = 0V, you should see that VCM = +Vs / 2 anyways. If you don't then you should review how you hooked the circuit up.

Comment: @RohatKılıç thank you. I tied -Vs to GND and +Vs is 5V. I am getting 5V on Vcm. My ADCs Vcm stays at around 0.7V

Comment: Okay, let's fix this misunderstanding: Normally you don't provide a CM voltage for ADCs with differential inputs, because most of them have a Vcm **output**. For example, ADS4449 has a Vcm output of 1.15V. So, you should see a non-zero voltage at ADC's VCM pin. Plus, you can't expect to have a CM voltage before ADC input because 0.1u capacitors block them. Notes: 1) In my comment above, I was talking about input and output CM voltage, not the ADCs. 2) You can't get a CM of 5V unless you remove the bottom 500R. There is something wrong with your circuit.

Comment: @RohatKılıç so the ADC here is in internal reference mode?

Comment: Most likely, yes. But still, you should see a non-zero voltage at ADCs VCM output.

Comment: @RohatKılıç ah yes that makes sense.

Comment: @RohatKılıç the ADC says each input (INM, INP) has to swing around Vcm +-0.5V. This schematic has a gain of 3.2. My voltage source outputs only positive voltage. Should the max. output voltage be 0.5V/3.2 or 1V/3.2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117064/discussion-between-electrococuk-and-rohat-kilic).